# How can i run JavaFX 2.0 in Tizen mobile/tablet Linux, which Java or JavaFX i have to install?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javafx, javafx-2, tizen

In my Fedora box i have JavaFX 2.0 working. But how can i now deploy my JavaFX or JavaSE application to Tizen mobile/tablet linux?

Which Java/JavaFX vm i have to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX for embedded platforms is not yet available.